# ListView Scrolling With Horizontal and Vertical in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am stuck on creating a `Listview` that supports horizontal and vertical scrolling, like this:

[image]

I don't understand how to achieve this type of `ListView` in Xamarin forms.

Comment: Avoid using ListView in such cases, You need a Grid inside a ScrollView, where Grids width and height will be sum of widths of columns and sum of height of rows.

Comment: Like Yogesh has said, use `ScrollView` to wrap the `ListView` will cause performance problem.

Comment: You can find something on GitHub 

https://github.com/akgulebubekir/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid

https://github.com/akgulebubekir/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid

Otherwise, I have used this.

https://devexpress.com/products/xamarin/

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve Horizontal & Vertical Listview by Custom Control. Kindly Refer this Code,

**1) Extend Scrollview Properties for renderized Listview**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace ProjectName.CustomControls
{
public class HorizontalListview : ScrollView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(HorizontalListview), default(IEnumerable));

        public IEnumerable ItemsSource
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemTemplateProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("ItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(HorizontalListview), default(DataTemplate));

        public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
        {
            get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
        }

        public event EventHandler<ItemTappedEventArgs> ItemSelected;

        public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedCommandProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("SelectedCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(HorizontalListview), null);

        public ICommand SelectedCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(SelectedCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedCommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedCommandParameterProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("SelectedCommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(HorizontalListview), null);

        public object SelectedCommandParameter
        {
            get { return GetValue(SelectedCommandParameterProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedCommandParameterProperty, value); }
        }


        public void Render()
        {
            if (ItemTemplate == null || ItemsSource == null)
                return;

            var layout = new StackLayout();
           layout.Spacing = 0;

            layout.Orientation = Orientation == ScrollOrientation.Vertical ? StackOrientation.Vertical : StackOrientation.Horizontal;

            foreach (var item in ItemsSource)
            {
                var command = SelectedCommand ?? new Command((obj) =>
                {
                    var args = new ItemTappedEventArgs(ItemsSource, item);
                    ItemSelected?.Invoke(this, args);
                });
                var commandParameter = SelectedCommandParameter ?? item;

                var viewCell = ItemTemplate.CreateContent() as ViewCell;
                viewCell.View.BindingContext = item;
                viewCell.View.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
                {
                    Command = command,
                    CommandParameter = commandParameter,
                    NumberOfTapsRequired = 1
                });
                layout.Children.Add(viewCell.View);
            }

            Content = layout;
        }
    }
```

**2) Include Namespace in your XAML Page**

```
xmlns:control="clr-namespace:ProjectName"
```

**3) Use Control in your Design**

```
<control:HorizontalListview Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="lst">                   
                    <control:HorizontalListview.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Label Style="{StaticResource lblPlaceNumberRing}" />
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </control:HorizontalListview.ItemTemplate>
                </control:HorizontalListview>
```

**4) Make Renderer for Android**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using ProjectName;
using ProjectName.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;


[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HorizontalListview), typeof(HorizontalListviewRendererAndroid))]

namespace ProjectName.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class HorizontalListviewRendererAndroid : ScrollViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var element = e.NewElement as HorizontalListview;
            element?.Render();

            if (e.OldElement != null)
                e.OldElement.PropertyChanged -= OnElementPropertyChanged;

            e.NewElement.PropertyChanged += OnElementPropertyChanged;

        }

        protected void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ChildCount > 0)
            {
                GetChildAt(0).HorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false;
                GetChildAt(0).VerticalScrollBarEnabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**5) Make Renderer for iOS**

```
using System;
using UIKit;
using ProjectName.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using ProjectName;
using System.ComponentModel;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HorizontalListview), typeof(HorizontalListviewRendererIos))]

namespace ProjectName.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class HorizontalListviewRendererIos : ScrollViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var element = e.NewElement as HorizontalListview;
            element?.Render();
            if (e.OldElement != null)
                e.OldElement.PropertyChanged -= OnElementPropertyChanged;

            e.NewElement.PropertyChanged += OnElementPropertyChanged;
        }

        protected void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
            this.ShowsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
            this.AlwaysBounceHorizontal = false;
            this.AlwaysBounceVertical = false;
            this.Bounces = false;

        }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to just have a `ScrollView` around the `ListView` but that causes unpleasant behaviour if the `ListView` is responsible for the vertical scrolling while the `ScrollView` does the horizontal scrolling. So you have to ensure that the `ListView` doesn't scroll in any direction and the `ScrollView` does in both directions.

The latter is is easy to achive by just setting:

```
scrollView.Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Both;
```

Preventing the scrolling of the `ListView` is a bit more tricky. Apparently the only way to do it is to ensure that the `ListView.HeightRequest` is greater than it actually needs. I ended up doing it like this:

```
listView.HeightRequest = listView.RowHeight * (ListUsedAsItemSource.Count + 1) + 1;
```

The `+ 1` inside the brackets is to set a bit of height for the  headers too. If you don't have headers you can omit it. Also be aware that you will have to set the `listView.RowHeight` manually (the default value is 40 I think). In my case without setting it on my own it was -1.

As a `ListView` doesn't scroll horizontally you don't have to prevent anything here. But per default the `ListView` will fit to the horizontal space. So you also have to set the `WidthRequest` similar to the `HeightRequest` above. Anyways, you won't be able to get something like a column width from the `ListView` so you'll have define a value on your own (and also use that value as the `WidthRequest` of your columns)

Comment: Be aware that with this solution the lazy loading of the `ListView` won't work anymore and you will have all elements loaded all the time. So for (potentially) big datasets this is not an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RecyclerView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/recycler-view/). I have uploaded a demo on  [github](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/RecycleViewScrolling).

You can download it, and test it. This project uses the `RecyclerView` to wrap another `RecyclerView`.

Comment: I want in xamarin forms, you have any idea of customization.

Comment: Hi, @sumitsisodia, sorry, I haven't seen your project is Xamarin.forms. I will try it. Have you used any third part lib?